# Neural Network String Normalization

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, normalization, prediction

I am attempting to form a product string normalization algorithm and am curious if this can be modeled using a neural network.

For example, I have the following input and target output data from eBay:

**Input String 1:** Brand New, Air Jordan 11 Retro XL Space Jam Size 10-US, Free Ship!

**Target Output String 1:** Space Jam Nike Air Jordan

**Input String 2:** Air Jordan 11 Retro XI 2016 Nike Space Jam 45 Men AJ11 DS Monstars 378037-003

**Target Output String 2:** Space Jam Nike Air Jordan

**Input String 3:** 2016 Nike Air Jordan Retro XI Space Jam US 8.5 - 9.5 IN HAND 11 378037 003 OG

**Target Output String 3:** Space Jam Nike Air Jordan

**Input String 4:** Air Jordans Nike 11 Retro XI 2016 45 Men AJ11 DS Monstars 378037-003

**Target Output String 4:** Space Jam Nike Air Jordan

If I feed the algorithm a new string, I'd like it to output something similar to below:

**Input String:** 2016 Air Jordan Retro 11 XI "Space Jam" MEN'S & GS Size 4Y-15 Nike

**Target Output String:** Space Jam Nike Air Jordan

I have used a CRF algorithm to do this somewhat successfully, but that requires preparing/bucketing the input strings/tokens into specific POS or attribute categories, which isn't really necessary here.

Instead, what I'd like to do is feed the input and output strings/tokens into a neural net, and have it give me a predicted output string based on the tokens that are present in a new string.

What I've tried so far is creating a sparse matrix with all of the input tokens and creating a model with the entire result string as an output, but this doesn't have great results.

Is there a better way to go about this? Thanks.